# How to use merge two columns in pandas so that result should have the same number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two dataframe which look like these:

```
df1 :
   
    ID    name    product  
0   1     sara    t-shirt
1   2     john    jacket
.
.
.
200 8     karen   hoodie

number of rows: 200

df2 :

    ID        Mark
0   1         zara
1   3         h&m
.
.
.
35  8         nike

number of rows : 35
```

what I want to do is to merge these two dataframe by column ''ID'' and have this line of code:

```
merge_ID = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
```

the expecting output should have the same number of rows like we have in df1 which is 200. The problem with my code is that the output has more rows than df1 e.g. 480 .
I don't understand why. Can you tell me, what the problem is?
Any help will be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Have you got duplicate ID values in your `df2`?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is this:

```
merge_ID = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='left')
```